# Order changes when using print vs println

Tags: clojure, monads, purely-functional

I've been experimenting with creating monads in clojure so I can separate my pure code from my impure code more thouroghly, and I've stumbled upon something strage with ordering.

When using the following code for a minimum use-case, the desired output is for it to print "Please enter your name: " to the screen and then take a single line of input, which is then printed back out to the screen. The code below is what should be able to acccomplish this:

```
    ;; IO Monad definitions

    (defn io-bind
      [mv mf]
      (fn []
        (let [val (mv)
              f (mf val)]
          (f))))

    ;; Monadic functions

    (defn io-print
      [msg]
      (fn []
        (print msg)))

    (defn io-read-line
      [_]
      (fn []
        (read-line)))

    ;; Entry point

    (defn -main
      "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
      [& args]
      ((-> (io-print "Please enter your name: ")
           (io-bind io-read-line)
           (io-bind io-print))))
```

I've experienced a hitch with this however, in that it will first poll for input from the user using `(read-line)` and only *afterwards* will it then print "Please enter your name: ".

In larger examples, it will still perform all of the visible IO actions in the proper order, for example in this case it does print out "Please enter your name: " before it prints out what you inputted, yet it still requests that input first.

The strangest part however is that the instant I replace `print` with `println` in `io-print` it does all of the ordering as intented, regardless of circumstance.

Why might this be occuring? Is there some way that `print` is lazy that `println` is not, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the following after the `print`:

```
(flush)
```

`println` will implicitly flush the output to the screen, so that is why you are seeing different behavior than with `print`.

Please see https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/flush for more info, as [also the source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3685) for all the details.